# IKImageView move tool not working in Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave, ikimageview

My app Plumb-Bob is based on the IKImageViewDemo:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/IKImageViewDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004049

I compile it for MacOS 10.10+ and in my tests I noticed that the "move tool" is not working at all in Mojave (10.14) while it does as usual in the previous systems.

Since I have strongly modified IKImageViewDemo for my purposes, I have downloaded it again to make some test (see link above).
When build and run IKImageViewDemo I have verified that it has the same behavior:

On MacOS 10.14 the move tool shows its open hand cursor, but, when dragging, the image is not moved at all.
On older MacOS, it works like a charm.

I did not find any updates, deprecations and changes on IKImageView framework in 10.14, searching at Apple Developer's docs.
Can anyone address me to the solution, it is very important, in my app, to move around the zoomed image.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It happens to my app named Overlay too. It seems that IKImageView is to be abandoned soon ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where did you get that info? Is there a workaround to get the move tool work again or we have to rewrite our applications using NSImageView?